# Issue with PrimeNG Library in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm encountering an issue with the PrimeNG library in my Angular application. Despite integrating PrimeNG components, the display remains unaffected and doesn't reflect the expected changes. I've followed the documentation thoroughly, but the problem persists.

Could anyone provide insights into potential causes or solutions for this issue? I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this matter effectively.

I tried to install the library again and again

Comment: It is important to note that I have no errors in the code or browser

Comment: Please show your code and explain the expected result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.